# parsing \\xc3\\xb6 from a url

Tags: php, utf-8

I'm trying to support an API, it's a remote server pushing data to me. When passing data, reading directly from $_GET['value'] I get strings with this in them:
\xc3\xb6

They also needed a very specific url structure, which I've had to use curl to work around. When using curl on the api I get this instead:
\xc3\xb6

Is the problem on my side or on his? How can I decode this reliably? Is there a better way than using curl available? (If neccesary I'll recode that part of it to skip curl, I just wanna get it working at this point).

//edit : Note that I'm writing the $_GET['value'] directly to a file to test. And it looks the same.

Comment: Can you describe why you need to use curl, and can you use curl on the command line to see output? What do the headers say about encoding?

Comment: Looks like escaped UTF-8. Seems like a bug on their side to me if they actually send "\xc3\xb6" (8 characters). If this is the case the encoding given in the headers does not matter much.

Comment: **\xc3\xb6** seems to be **&#246** which seems to be **ö**